# How does the cocos2d rendering engine work in detail? Does it render in the background?

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x

Does the cocos2d render engine render in the background, or is everything happening on the main thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one thread. period. (rare exception : loading textures asynchronously).

Comment: Do you have a link to a resource which describes this?

Comment: Read this thread, in particular riq"s comment about thread safety. Basically he is saying that it all runs on the main thread. https://code.google.com/u/111588202880883771967/ . It is oldy, but i have no reason to believe there has been any change since. In particular, if you step out in your own thread-land, make certain anything that updates ui is performed on the main thread via a gcd wrap.